# How to access elements in std::map template variable without specifying template variable?

Tags: c++, templates

I want a `std::map` variable which take a `std::string` key and value of any type:

```cpp
template <typename T>
std::map<std::string, T> general;

general<A>["a"] = new A;
general<B>["b"] = new B;
general<C>["c"] = new C;
```

But i don't want to specify template variable in every time that i used, so i wrote this:

```cpp
class general_one
{
public:
    general_one& operator[](const char* key)
    {
        m_current_key = key;
        return *this;
    }

    template <typename T>
    void operator=(T&& block)
    {
        m_blocks<T>[m_current_key] = std::forward<T>(block);

    }

private:
    template <typename T>
    static inline std::map<std::string, T> m_blocks;

    std::string m_current_key;
};
```

And now i can use it as i want:

```cpp
general_one general;

general["a"] = new A;
general["b"] = new B;
general["c"] = new C;
```

But still in `at()` member function implementation i must specify template variable:

```cpp
template <typename T>
T& at(const char* key)
{
    return m_blocks<T>[key];
}
```

```
general_one a;
a["ghasem"] = new int(12);
a["another"] = new double(.32);
a["again_another"] = new float(.34f);

std::clog << *a.at<int*>("ghasem") << std::endl;
```

Is there any way to avoid requirement for specifying type in `at()` member function ?

Comment: Unless you save the key along with its type to do a lookup, you have to specify the type.

Comment: This is creating several maps, one for each `T`. I could do `general["a"] = new A; general["a"] = new B;` and now you definitely cannot automatically decide the return type of `general.at("a")`, because the key `"a"` refers both to an `A*` and a `B*`, nevermind that that information is only available at runtime anyway. Are you entirely sure you're going about this the right way? Would a `std::map<std::string, std::any>` be enough?

Comment: @HTNW, I want to avoid casting.

Comment: This looks like it might be an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What bigger problem are you trying to solve with this map?

Comment: C++ is a strongly typed language. It doesn't handle variable s that could be anything very well. It's pretty rare to want a container that can contain anything, and when you do want it, it's probably because you have a conceptual problem that's going to lead to very nasty problems further down the line. Containers of derived classes or a limited number of informally related classes, that happens, but any type forces you to store type information and cast or store a generic format and convert..

Comment: Perhaps instead of storing values of different types, you should store what you can do with those values? That is, wrap everything into type erasing containers: `struct value { virtual ~value() = default; virtual void doThing1() = 0; virtual int doThing2(double) = 0; /* everything you want to do with the values etc. as pure virtual functions */ }; template<typename T> struct value_impl : value { T self; template<typename... U> value_impl(std::in_place_t, U&&... u) : self(std::forward<U>(u)...) { } /* implementations */ }; std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<value>> general;`